# Heap sort with extending Collections

Tags: java, sorting

Hi i was wondering how you would go about having a heapsort algorithim and making it able to handle arrays of integers and float numbers so far i have the following for code :

```
   private static int[] a; //variable that stores the value of the array
   private static String[] names; //used for the names of the array
   private static int lengtha;// used for determing the size of the array
   private static int left;
   private static int right;
   private static int largest;


   private static void buildheap(int []a){
        lengtha=a.length-1; //gets the size of the array
        for(int i=lengtha/2;i>=0;i--){
            maxheap(a,i);
        }
    }

   private static void maxheap(int[] a, int i){ 
        left=2*i;
        right=2*i+1;
        if(left <= lengtha && a[left] > a[i]){
            largest=left;
        }
        else{
            largest=i;
        }

        if(right <= lengtha && a[right] > a[largest]){
            largest=right;
        }
        if(largest!=i){
            exchange(i,largest);
            maxheap(a, largest);
        }
    }

   private static void exchange(int i, int j){
        int t=a[i];
        String temp = names[i];

        a[i]=a[j];

        a[j]=t; 

        names[i]= names[j];
        names[j]=temp;
        }

    public Heap(int []a0, String[] arr){
        a=a0;
        names=arr;
        buildheap(a);

        for(int i=lengtha;i>0;i--){
            exchange(0, i);
            lengtha=lengtha-1;
            maxheap(a, 0);
        }
```

Comment: @Niks Tyagi we should figure it out, wait ..

Comment: Is the problem that it isn't working?  If so, please give more details.  Or if there's a part of it that you just don't know how to write in Java, please point out specifically where.  But if this is just part of a program and you're asking us to "finish it for you", I don't think you'll get any answers.

Comment: No im wondering how to make this code work with float numbers as well with using the collections class and generics